# Where can I find another version of the "contrib.url" package?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit my code but I get this error and I cannot find another version of this package that works for my version of R.

Does anyone have another version of this package I can try?

```
install.packages("contrib.url")
```

> Warning in install.packages :   package ‘contrib.url’ is not available
> for this version of R
>
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available
> elsewhere, see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

`devtools::install_version("contrib.url", version = "1.0.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you.